# I'm trying to index an array of nodes (linked lists)

Tags: arrays, c, nodes, bin, radix

Node struct implementation:

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;
typedef node* nodePtr;
```

Appending to my node:

```
// Append to node
void addTo(nodePtr* aNode, int val){
    //Create a new node to hold the value
   nodePtr temp = (nodePtr) malloc(sizeof(node));
   temp->data = val;
   temp->next = NULL;
   if(!(*aNode)){
       *aNode = temp;
       return;
   }
   nodePtr curr = *aNode;
   while(curr->next){
       curr = curr->next;
   }
   curr->next = temp;
}
```

Displaying my node:

```
void display(nodePtr aNode){
    nodePtr curr = aNode;
    while(curr){
        printf("%d \n", curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

So my problem here's that I'm trying to create an array of nodes and insert values into each node, while indexing said array. But I'm not getting it to work.

Here's the main stub for what I'm trying to do:

```
int main(){
    nodePtr* myArr = (nodePtr*) malloc(3*sizeof(nodePtr));
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < 3){
        while((j%3)!=0){
            addTo(&myArr[i], j);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        display(myArr[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I print it, I don't get any thing. Do I need to instantiate every node in the array first before I can get it to work?

Comment: How it `myArr` defined? Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: `while(curr->next)` that part is wrong in the `display` function. That will always miss printing the last node since `curr->next` is always NULL for the last node.

Comment: @kaylum just did that

Comment: The pointers stored in the memory allocated for `myArr` are uninitialized. You must either explicitly zero them, or allocate with `calloc` instead. You should not be casting the return value from `malloc`, unless you're actually compiling this with C++ in which case you shouldn't use allocation functions from the C library at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two major issues with this program. The first is that you have not initialized your list pointers. You allocate storage for them, but their actual values can be anything. Attempting to dereference such values will result in Undefined Behavior.

You could `memset` after calling `malloc`, but it is recommended to use `calloc` for your allocation instead, which will also zero-initialize the memory (*i.e.* set all bytes to zero, which is equivalent to all the pointers being NULL):

```
nodePtr* myArr = calloc(3, sizeof(nodePtr));
```

The second issue is you never push anything onto the lists. The reason is that `j` is initially zero and so your *while-loop* is never entered (the condition `(j%3)!=0` is false).

You could have detected this by stepping through your program with a debugger attached, or selectively adding `printf` statements to inspect which parts of your program execute. For example, adding `printf("addTo() called\n");` at the top of the `addTo` function would have immediately alerted you to the fact it is never called.

One way to fix it is with a *do-while* instead:

```
do {
    addTo(&myArr[i], j);
    j++;
} while((j % 3) != 0);
```

With this type of loop, the body is always executed before testing the loop condition. That allows `j` to be modified in the loop before being checked.

By applying these fixes for the two issues I've identified, your program operates the way you intended.

Comment: Thanks, the fixes helped, but my expected output in the print portion is "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7" but I'm getting "0,1,3,4,6,7". 

Debugging shows that 2 & 5 get added respectively, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I can see from your new question edits that you're confused. I told you to make just these two changes. Exactly as written. It's quite pointless you telling me my fixes didn't help if you didn't apply them. See [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n4n7K9hcf) of what I had expected you to do with this answer.